# Candidate Keys on Functional Dependencies?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, functional-dependencies

The relation R=(A,B,C,D,E) and functional dependencies F are given as follows:

F={A->BC, CD->E, B->D, E->A}

> E, BC and CD can be a candidate keys, but B cannot.

---

Anyone could point me how this fact is calculated? I google it but couldn't understand more as what I known before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the dependent attributes of a given set of attributes by computing the closure of its functional dependencies. Let me demonstrate:

```
A -> ABC -> ABCD -> ABCDE
```

`A` determines `BC` (given) as well as itself (trivially) therefore `A -> ABC`. Add the fact that `B -> D` to get `ABC -> ABCD`. Finally, add `CD -> E` to get `ABCD -> ABCDE`. We stop here because we've determined the whole relation, therefore `A` is a candidate key.

You should verify that, starting from `E`, `BC` and `CD`, you can indeed determine the whole relation.

Starting from `B`, we get:

```
B -> BD
```

and that's it. The rest of the relation can't be determined from `BD`, so it's not a candidate key.

A more visual way of doing it is to sketch the functional dependencies:

[image: Functional dependency graph]

Starting from any set of attributes, try finding a path to every other attribute by following the arrows. You can only get to `E` if you start at `E` or visited both `C` and `D`.

From `B`, you can reach `D`, but without `C`, you're not allowed to go to `E`, which also excludes `A`. So `B` can't be a candidate key.

Comment: So how it's calculate from above graph?

Comment: would you please add more about the shortest way that you proposed here (i.e Graph)?

Comment: Follow every available arrow starting from the given set of attributes. If you can reach all the other nodes, you've got a candidate key. If not, then not.

Comment: It means AND, as in you can only go to `E` if you've visited `C` AND `D`.

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks. I think there is a typo in first paragraph of functional dependency, please check !

Comment: I don't see a typo.